# Storing generic controller function in services in order to get them in isolated scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-service

I have an Angular UI modal that I would like to use the following method on, I used to keep it on the controller that wraps my entire application(metaCtrl), but the modal seems to create his own isolated scope(known issue).

My solution was to store this function at a service and return it from the service into the scope anywhere I need it.

The problem is that I don't have a reference to the current scope this way, and adding another parameter to the function will be an over head.

Tried using $eval, $injector, and even injecting $scope manually, nothing seems to work.

```
factory('utils', function($location, $http, $window, $rootScope, $injector, API_URL, WBSITE_HOST){
    var baseUrl = API_URL;
    var staticUrl = WBSITE_HOST;
    var config = {withCredentials: true, headers:{'Accept-Language':"en"}};
    var prevLang = undefined;

    var helpers = {
        scope: {},
        showNotification: function(type, duration, msg, elmName){
                            var $scope = this.scope || $injector.get("$scope");
                            if(type == "success"){

                                var $scope = $injector.get("$scope");
                                $scope.layout.success.message = msg;
                                $scope.layout.success.visible = true;

                                if(duration === null)
                                    return

                                $timeout(function(){
                                    $scope.layout.success.visible = false;
                                    $scope.layout.success.message = "";
                                }, duration);
                            }
                            else if(type == "error"){
                                if(elmName)
                                    $scope.layout.error.focusElm = elmName;
                                    $scope.layout.error.message = msg;
                                    $scope.layout.error.visible = true;

                                if(duration === null)
                                    return

                                $timeout(function(){
                                    $scope.layout.error.visible = false;
                                    $scope.layout.error.message = "";
                                }, duration);
                            }
                            else if(type == "persistent"){
                                $scope.layout.persistent.message = msg;
                                $scope.layout.persistent.visible = true;
                            }
                        },
        closeNotification:  function(){
                                var $scope = this.scope || $injector.get("$scope");
                                $scope.layout = $scope.layout ? $scope.layout : {};
                                $scope.layout.success = $scope.layout.success ? $scope.layout.success : {};
                                $scope.layout.error = $scope.layout.error ? $scope.layout.error : {};
                                $scope.layout.persistent = $scope.layout.persistent ? $scope.layout.persistent : {};

                                $scope.layout.success.visible = false;
                                $scope.layout.success.message = "";
                                $scope.layout.error.visible = false;
                                $scope.layout.error.message = "";
                                // $scope.layout.persistent.visible = false;
                                // $scope.layout.persistent.message = "";
                            }
    }
    return{
        getHelper: function(param, scope){
            helpers.scope = scope;
            return helpers[param];
        }
   }
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I've had a similar issue. I ended up not using a modal, because of the nested scope issue. However, the more I think about it the more I think using a directive is the right way to go.  Then give it a transclude=true; This will allow it everything you're using it for, and give the directive the Ctrl's scope.  I don't know if this is the best way, but I'm pretty sure it will work. 
http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Comment: Perhaps fn.call($scope) can work, still no idea how to implement it though